# Change the file system of a partition without deleting its content

Tags: ext4, gpt, partition-table, exfat

I have a 2tb hard drive containing gpt and a single 2tb partition with ext4 file system. The partition has one 1.5tb file inside it. I want to change the type of file system of this partition from ext4 to exfat without deleting the 1.5tb file. Can I do that without writing a custom program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool which some people have successfully used to convert Ext4 partitions to exFAT in place, [`fstransform`](https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform). Note that the tool doesn’t officially support conversions to exFAT, and I haven’t tried it — but [there are apparently reports of it working](https://fedoramagazine.org/transform-file-systems-in-linux/) (with the `--force-untested-file-systems` flag).

In any case you should have a backup of your file before attempting this, in which case you might as well reformat and restore your file from backup.